# MKR1000 and DS18B20 temperature sensor

Tags: temperature-sensor, mkr1000, ds18b20

I am new to Arduino and electronics in general and I can't get my MKR1000 to read correct data from a DS18B20 temperature sensor.

Here is the [tutorial](https://create.arduino.cc/projecthub/TheGadgetBoy/ds18b20-digital-temperature-sensor-and-arduino-9cc806) I followed.

**The issue is**: I always get the same readings from the sensor: `-127.00`.

I should mention I have tried 2 different sensors and get the same readings.

From the sensor, GND goes directly to GND on the board, and I have the 4.7kΩ resistor in between the data and power wires.

According to the sensor manufacturer, output leads: Yellow (VCC), Red (DATA), Black (GND).

Data line is connected to the pin `~2` on the MKR1000.

```
/********************************************************************/
// First we include the libraries
#include <OneWire.h> 
#include <DallasTemperature.h>
/********************************************************************/
// Data wire is plugged into pin 2 on the Arduino 
#define ONE_WIRE_BUS 2 
/********************************************************************/
// Setup a oneWire instance to communicate with any OneWire devices  
// (not just Maxim/Dallas temperature ICs) 
OneWire oneWire(ONE_WIRE_BUS); 
/********************************************************************/
// Pass our oneWire reference to Dallas Temperature. 
DallasTemperature sensors(&oneWire);
/********************************************************************/ 
void setup(void) 
{ 
 // start serial port 
 Serial.begin(9600); 
 Serial.println("Dallas Temperature IC Control Library Demo"); 
 // Start up the library 
 sensors.begin(); 
} 
void loop(void) 
{ 
 // call sensors.requestTemperatures() to issue a global temperature 
 // request to all devices on the bus 
/********************************************************************/
 Serial.print(" Requesting temperatures..."); 
 sensors.requestTemperatures(); // Send the command to get temperature readings 
 Serial.println("DONE"); 
/********************************************************************/
 Serial.print("Temperature is: "); 
 Serial.print(sensors.getTempCByIndex(0)); // Why "byIndex"?  
   // You can have more than one DS18B20 on the same bus.  
   // 0 refers to the first IC on the wire 
   delay(1000); 
}
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: In addition to the photos, do you have a schematic for the circuit to upload?  It would be more helpful than looking at the bunch of wires to figure out what is going on.

Comment: Thanks @MichaelT - This question has been answered already. Sensor manufacturer messed up their documentation so I had the power going to the data and vice-versa.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you have it wired wrong.  A schematic would really help but it looks like you've got 5V going directly into the sensors data line (yellow wire) it's connected on your breadboard to the orange wire +5V.  The power wire of your temperature sensor (red wire) is running through a 4.7K resistor which is not likely what you wanted here either.

Comment: According to the sensor manufacturer: Output leads: Yellow (VCC), Red (DATA), Black (GND)

Comment: May be a typo in their documentation.  I've found similar sensors on Ebay and:  Output lead: red (VCC), yellow(DATA) , black(GND)

Comment: The schema I am trying to achieve can be found on the link I posted earlier: https://create.arduino.cc/projecthub/TheGadgetBoy/ds18b20-digital-temperature-sensor-and-arduino-9cc806#toc-step-4--build-simple-circuit-3

Comment: OMG! Okay... you were right, they managed to get their schemas wrong! Red is VCC and yellow is DATA! I thought about many possible causes but not that one... ;) Thanks for your help.

Comment: The only thing worse than no documentation is errant documentation.